# Regular Expressions - two different occurrence in one group per line (group in group)

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to get a specific value from the group?

Example:

```
TEST TEST 0,00 € 23,00 €
TEST TEST 1219,51 €
TEST TEST 50,11 €
TEST 1,11 €
TEST TEST TEST 313,31 €
TEST 123,13 € 50,23 €
TEST TEST TEST TEST 313,13 €
TEST 13,23 €
```

expected resaults:

```
TEST TEST 0,00 € 23,00 € <-- Group1 0,00 Group2 23,00
TEST TEST 1219,51 € <-- Group1 1219,51
TEST TEST 50,11 € <-- Group1 50,11
TEST 1,11 € <-- Group1 1,11
TEST TEST TEST 313,31 € <-- Group1 313,31
TEST 123,13 € 50,23 € <-- Group1 123,13 <-- Group2 50,23
TEST TEST TEST TEST 313,13 € <-- Group1 313,13
TEST 13,23 € <-- Group1 13,23
```

I tried to do it this way:
`(?P<first_price>\d+,\d+)|(?P<second_price>.*\d+,\d+.*\d+,\d+)`

But I have trouble with dividing these numbers within the second group
https://regex101.com/r/HD2qjh/1

Is it possible to divide it like that within one regular expression and some additional operators?

Comment: Try using this one: `(?P<first_price>\d+,\d+)(?P<second_price>(?<= € )\d+,\d+)?` >> https://regex101.com/r/fXGj3v/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
(?P<Group1>\d+,\d+)(?:[^\d\n]*(?P<Group2>\d+,\d+))?
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HD2qjh/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?P<Group1>\d+,\d+)`: Named capture group `Group1` to match and capture 1+ digit then comma then 1+ digit
- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `[^\d\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that is not a digit and not a line break
  - `(?P<Group2>\d+,\d+)`: Named capture group `Group2` to match and capture 1+ digit then comma then 1+ digit
- `)?`: End non-capture group. `?` makes this group *optional*

Comment: Your example works perfectly. The question is that is there any limitation on "nesting" groups? For example, I have a group and in it a group that I want to split into another two. Will there be any limitations in this case?

Comment: No, there is no limitation as such on capture groups. However you cannot extract from a repeating capture group like `(?:(\d+,\d+)[^\n\d]*)+` in python's `re` module